# Is it possible to re-transmit only the last packet at TCP flow?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

I try to understand the TCP behavior, especially re-transmission.

I did a small experiment and find the curious thing.

**The only last packet is re-transmitted. Why do this happen?**

I think if the last packet is time-out, then the other packets have to be time-out because All packets in the flow have same RTT and RTO.

At first, I think it is due to `delayed ack`. Therefore, I did a same experiment with `setsockopt` **TCP_QUICKACK**. But I saw the same phenomenon. ( But I am not sure yet, that the cause of this is not `delayed ack`. )

Could you give me a little help? Thank you for reading :)

---

For example,

[1] H1->H2 send a 1500 bytes packet

[2] H1->H2 send a 1500 bytes packet

[3] H1->H2 send a 1500 bytes packet

...

[n] H1->H2 send a 800 bytes packet **[the last packet]**

[n+1] H1->H2 **re-send** a 800 bytes packet **[the last packet]**

[n+2] H2->H1 send an ACK.

---

[the raw data from `wireshark`]

```
1735203 51.249349738    10.0.0.1    10.0.0.2    TCP 1514    35250 → 50021 
[ACK] Seq=16124342 Ack=1 Win=58 Len=1448 TSval=902298 TSecr=902296

1735204 51.249349999    10.0.0.1    10.0.0.2    TCP 1514    35250 → 50021 
[ACK] Seq=16125790 Ack=1 Win=58 Len=1448 TSval=902298 TSecr=902296

1735205 51.249350340    10.0.0.1    10.0.0.2    TCP 866 35250 → 50021 
[PSH, ACK] Seq=16127238 Ack=1 Win=58 Len=800 TSval=902298 TSecr=902296

1735207 51.258283589    10.0.0.1    10.0.0.2    TCP 866 
[TCP Retransmission] 35250 → 50021 [PSH, ACK] Seq=16127238 
Ack=1 Win=58 Len=800 TSval=902301 TSecr=902298

1735208 51.258288919    10.0.0.2    10.0.0.1    TCP 66  50021 → 35250 
[ACK] Seq=1 Ack=16128038 Win=32766 Len=0 TSval=902301 TSecr=902298
```

EDIT:

** Attached captured files **

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mtgtv5xof6octn/host2_data.pcapng?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mtgtv5xof6octn/host2_data.pcapng?dl=0

Each files is the packet captured at each host.

If you don't mind, please check the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think if the last packet is time-out, then the other packets have to be time-out because All packets in the flow have same RTT and RTO.

No. If the last *segment* transmission times out it's because it hasn't been ACKed within the RTO. All segments before seem to have been properly ACKed as they're not retransmitted.

This can be caused by a delayed ACK (when its delay+RTT is larger than RTO), or the segment or its ACK has actually been lost. A delayed ACK should be well below a realistic (RTO minus RTT), but it's not impossible to cause a retransmission.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You mean a delay ACK make this situation that only the last segment is lost and re-tranmitted. Could you explain it in detail? I know the behavior of delayed ACK that many segments can be acknowledged by at a time. But I couldn't understand how it make only the last segment re-transmitted. I appreciate you:)

Comment: The destination can delay an ACK in anticipation of additional data, saving the (single-segment) ACK overhead when it can ACK multiple segments just a bit later. Of course, an ACK delayed for too long (RTO-RTT) can cause a retransmission.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. But in the case that ACK is delayed for saving ACK overhead, not only the last segment but also the others wait a ACK from receiver. Therefore, I think all segments have to re-transmitted, not only the last segment. Could you fix my logic?

Comment: You were talking about a retransmit of the *last* segment, so apparently, all previous segments have been ACKed.

Comment: Yes I write about the re-transmit of the last segment. But host [10.0.0.2] doesn't send an ACK before the last one. I think the other previous segments didn't have an ACK before the one.

Comment: The pcaps show 10.0.0.2 ACKing all the time. Where's the problem?

Comment: At first glance, I think so too. But it seems host 10.0.0.2 didn't receive the ack for the other previous segment. I attached a screen shot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmgkpybhiodtqdb/picture1.png?dl=0 I really really really appreciate you..